# Residue field of a Artin local $\mathbb{C}$ algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings, artinian

My question is the following: I encountered the statement

*The residue field of an Artin local $\mathbb{C}$-algebra is $\mathbb{C}$*

I understand that if the algebra $A$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{C}$ this is true: $\mathbb{C} \subset A/\mathfrak{m}_A$ would be a field extension where the latter is finitely generated over $\mathbb{C}$ and thus it is a finite algebraic extension by the Zariski Lemma. However without the assumption for $A$ to be finitely generated it seems to me that the statement is not true.
$$\mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{C}(x) = A$$
It seems to me to be a counterexample.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\mathbb C(x)$ is Artinian, local and the residue is not isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. And your comments on finite generation are on-mark.

At nLab [I find this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Artin+ring):

> A local Artin algebra with residue field $\mathbb{K}$ is a **finitely generated** $\mathbb{K}$-algebra $A$.

So it seems the term "local Artin algebra" also assumes that $A$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb K$, and your example does not include that.

Comment: Yes, the subtle difference is 'Artin algebra' vs. 'artinian algebra'. It is very easy to stumble over this, though.

Comment: @MooS I was quite unaware of it myself, until I had a hunch this might be the case.

Comment: I didn't know it, thank you!